# how can a I use createpcocess to redirect the created process's stdout and stderr to a string stream?

Tags: winapi, window, createprocess, createprocessasuser

Here is the problem, I want to use createprocess to run a command in a win32 console program, but I want to be able to search through the stdout, stderr, and stdin after modifying data being sent in to the process.  This is so I can do some things underneath the hood and in some cases spawn an email which contains parts of the stdout and stderr.  I have found some examples of how to redirect the output to a file, but it isn't a file that I need since I want the output for manipulation and real time information access; waiting for the process to end before I get the full output is not an option since it will run for 10-20 days.
How can I create a process in win32 while being able to have access to the data coming out of stdout as a string stream, or like in nature, to achieve the goal I desire?  Can some one direct me to an example of this?

Comment: [Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `CreatePipe()` to create pipes for `CreateProcess()` to use for the redirection.  You would then read the process's output from the pipes as needed.

If you want the output in a `stringstream`, you have to read it from the pipe first and then assign it to the `stringstream` afterwards, or implement a custom `streambuf` or `istream` to grab the data from the pipes directly.